# HTTP 500 Error with Delphi Indy SOAP WSSE

Tags: delphi, soap, indy, wss

I want to send SOAP/XML data to a web service, but the service asks for WSSE security. In SOAPUI I did the tests, and configuring `OUTGOING WSS` works. I want to do this with Delphi Indy, what can I do to have the same results as SOAP UI with Delphi?

```pascal
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MemoryStream: TStringStream;
  cadena: string;     
  Resultado: string;
begin
  cadena := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"';
  cadena := cadena + ' xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia"> ';
  cadena := cadena + ' <soap:Header/> ';
  cadena := cadena + ' <soap:Body> ';
  cadena := cadena + ' <wcf:GetNumberingRange> ';
  cadena := cadena + ' !--Optional:-->';
  cadena := cadena + ' <wcf:accountCode>00000000000</wcf:accountCode>';
  cadena := cadena + ' <!--Optional:-->';
  cadena := cadena + ' <wcf:accountCodeT>000000000000</wcf:accountCodeT>';
  cadena := cadena + ' <!--Optional:-->';
  cadena := cadena + ' <wcf:softwareCode>XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</wcf:softwareCode>';
  cadena := cadena + ' </wcf:GetNumberingRange>';
  cadena := cadena + ' </soap:Body>';
  cadena := cadena + ' </soap:Envelope>';
  MemoryStream := tStringStream.Create;
  MemoryStream.WriteString(Cadena);
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Username := '';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := '';
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('SOAPAction', 'mustUnderstand="1"');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Text);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(MemoryStream.DataString);
  try
    Resultado := IdHTTP1.Post('https://vpfe.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc', MemoryStream);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Text);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Resultado);
  end;
```

The service shows HTTP 500 error, and I know that is because of the incomplete request, the missing `WSS OUTGOING`.

Comment: Your XML is malformed. Also, you are requesting an HTTPS url, do you have an `SSLIOHandler` component, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, hooked up to your `TIdHTTP`? Also, I don't see any WSSE security elements in this code at all (no encryption, no authentication, nothing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry it's my first time doing this, and the one who answers me is the guru, I'm happy, well, in response to your question, yes, TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component is hooked up to TIdHTTP component, I have a p12 cert file, that I hooked up also to TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL with the password in the onGetPassword event, the WSSE security elements, I don't know how to build it, can you help me? The project I'm trying to do is consume the methods of Colombia DIAN(IRS) service, https://vpfe.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc?wsdl, Thanks in advance